# Session variable arrangement for user management in multiple roles

Tags: php, session-variables, user-management

How can I manage same session variables for two users one admin and another his subordinate. so that admin can visit in his sub-ordinate user accounts without getting logged out of his own ??

Answer (score 0):

So you have two user groups admin and staffs. I would have designed the database as tbl_users(id, username, usertype). Here usertype is an enum containing either 'admin' for admin or 'staff' for staff. When the user logs in, i would put the usertype and username in the session variable. Depending on this value (usertype) I would allow admin and staff functions. i.e. if usertype is admin then allow the user to query all the other staff data, else dont allow.

Comment: The DB table is already same for both groups and like I said, I've the same session variable for both staff & admin as I treat them as company users and the variables are userId & userType, so now if admin logs in any staff user account, the session gets updated with userId and userType as staff. But the admin session gets destroyed or you can say updated with the new ones. I want my admin/supervisor to login in staff user account to see stuff how the staff users see, but also want to save his admin session so that he can take a look on another staff account after visiting one.